# Why does using super() in a __call__ method on a metaclass raise TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, metaclass

I'm using Python 3, and I found that I can't use `super()` within `__call__` of metaclass.

Why in the code below does `super()` raise a `TypeError: 'ListMetaclass' object is not iterable` exception? Why does it works well if I remove the `__call__` method from the metaclass?

```
class ListMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['add'] = lambda self, value: self.append(value)
        new_cls = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return new_cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        ### why the 'super()' here raises TypeError: 'ListMetaclass' object is not iterable
        return super().__call__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return super(__class__, cls).__call__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return super(__class__, cls.__class__).__call__(cls, *args, **kw)

class MyList(list, metaclass=ListMetaclass):
    a=1
    def bar(self):
        print('test');

L=MyList()
L.add(1)
print('Print MyList :', L)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pass in `cls` to `super().__call__()`; `super()` takes care of binding for you and so `cls` is *already* passed in automatically.

You may have gotten confused by the `super().__new__(cls, ...)` call in `__new__`; that's because `__new__` is the exception here, see the [`object.__new__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> Called to create a new instance of class `cls. __new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument.

Removing `cls` from the `super().__call__(...)` expression works:

```
class ListMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['add'] = lambda self, value: self.append(value)
        new_cls = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return new_cls;
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return super().__call__(*args, **kw)
```

By passing in `cls`, you are effectively executing `list(cls)`, telling `list()` to convert `cls` to values in the new list; that required `cls` to be an iterable.

When you remove the `__call__` method on your metaclass, the default `type.__call__` method is used when you call `MyClass()`, which just receives the normal arguments (none in your example) and returns a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

I can see where this will be confusing because you have to pass `cls` to `super().__new__` but you **mustn't** pass it to `super().__call__`.

That's because `__call__` is a normal method but `__new__` is special. It's [behaving like a `staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> #### `object.__new__(cls[, ...])`
>
> Called to create a new instance of class `cls`. `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) [...]

As staticmethod it **needs all arguments** while you don't need to pass the first argument to normal methods (it's already bound).

So just change it to:

```
return super().__call__(*args, **kw)
```

inside `__call__`.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a method of the super class using `super().method` will already *bind* the method to the current instance. So the `self` argument for methods will already be set automatically, just like when you call `self.method()`.

So when you then pass the current instance (in this case, the `cls` type) to the method, you are actually passing it a second time.

```
super().__call__(cls, *args, **kw)
```

So this will end up making a call `__call__(cls, cls, *args, **kw)`.

When this is then interpreted by your `__call__` method, the arguments will then be matched to the following definition:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
```

So the first `cls` is properly matched, but the second `cls` is interpreted to be the variable parameter list `*args`. And here’s where your exception comes from: `cls` is being passed where an iterable is expected, but `cls`, the class `ListMetaclass`, is not iterable.

So the fix here is simply to remove that additional `cls`: `super().method()` will already include it automatically due to method binding.